# How do you check if a file exists within awk? [-d 'filename'] failing

Tags: bash, awk, directory

I'm trying to generate a list of users who have a home directory set which does not exist. It seems I should be able to do this with awk, but something is wrong with my syntax.

It keeps telling me "Invalid Syntax" at the ]. What am I doing wrong?

```
awk -F: '{ if(![ -d "$6"]){ print $1 " " $3 " " $7}}' /etc/passwd
```

The final code I'm probably going to end up using is:

```
awk -F: '{if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 1 && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" ) {print "The directory " $6 " does not exist for user " $1 }}' /etc/passwd
```

And I have [a related question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195151/displaying-no-results-when-awk-command-has-no-output).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use

```
system(command)
    Execute the operating-system command command and then
    return to the awk program. Return command’s exit status.
```

e.g.:

```
awk -F: '{if(system("[ ! -d " $6 " ]") == 0) {print $1 " " $3 " " $7}}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for some reason, so I had to do this: awk '{if(system("stat " $0 " >/dev/null 2>/dev/null") == 1) print $0}'

Comment: @AlexanderKjäll - this tests for the existence of a directory - if you're trying to see whether _a regular file_ exists then it is obvious that the above code will fail...

Comment: **This is extremely dangerous!**  Depending on the input **arbitrary commands may be executed**.  For example following executes `/bin/ls`:  `echo ';ls;' | awk '{ print system("[ ! -d " $1 " ]") }'`

Comment: Is there no better way to test if a directory exists than firing a new process? This seems extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that `[ -d ]` is an `awk` thing, that's a shell thing. I would just do it this way instead:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1,$3,$7}' /etc/passwd | 
    while read name uid shell; do 
        [ -d "/home/$name" ] || echo "$name $uid $shell"; 
    done
```

Of course, as very correctly pointed out by @Janis, you can do the whole thing in the shell:

```
while IFS=: read  name x uid x x x shell rest; do
     [ -d "/home/$name" ] || echo "$name $uid $shell" 
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Ok, I think I actually want to pass $6 as dir, and do -d $dir, but this helps a lot. Now I just have to figure out how to echo "no results" if none are found. Thank-you!

Comment: Note that the `awk` isn't actually needed; since you loop in shell anyway you can also just do `while IFS=: read -r name x uid x x x shell rest ; do ... ; done </etc/passwd`.

Comment: @Doug Just do `awk -F: '{print $6}' /etc/passwd | while read dir; do [ -d "$dir" ] || echo "no results for $dir"; done`.

Comment: @Janis indeed, good point, answer edited.

Comment: As @terdon notes, `[ -d "$6"]` is actually bash syntax, not awk. The `[` looks like normal syntax, but (in one of bash/Linux's better weirdnesses) it's actually a synonym for the `test` executable program (or maybe a bash built-in version of it, and, just to be weirder, bash requires a matching `]` that doesn't do anything I'm aware of other than to mislead you to think that the whole thing is really syntax and not a program). In any case, it's not something awk knows about. That's why you need the `system()` function to access it by referencing it in the context of bash where it is understood

Comment: Please always use `read -r` (as already others noted) because without strange things might happen (as `read` interprets '\' as escape sequence).

Answer (score 8):

You can use *getline*:

```c
BEGIN {
   print getline < "file" < 0 ? "not exists" : "exists"
}
```

Comment: This is safe in `awk`, but unfortunately does not work for directories.

Answer (score 7):

If you are really using `gawk` (though you may be using `nawk`, or `mawk`, in which case this won't apply), you can do this *natively* using one of the [*loadable extensions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Samples.html) available since v4.0. I'm using `gawk-4.1.x` (v4.0 had a variation on the syntax for loading extensions).

Loading the `filefuncs` extension adds (amongst others) a `stat()` function:

```
@load "filefuncs"
BEGIN {FS=":"}
(NF==7) {
   printf("user: %s %i %i\n",$1,$3,$4)
   rc=stat($6,fstat)
   err=ERRNO  # ERRNO is a string, not an int!
   if (rc<0) { 
       printf(" error: %s rc=%i %s\n",$6,rc,err)
   } else {
      if (fstat["type"]!="directory") 
        printf("  ENOTDIR: %s %s\n",$6,fstat["type"])
      if (fstat["uid"]!=$3) 
        printf("  uid mismatch: %s %i!=%i\n",$6,fstat["uid"],$3)
      if (fstat["gid"]!=$4) 
        printf("  gid mismatch: %s %i!=%i\n",$6,fstat["gid"],$4)
   }
}
```

See the `filefuncs(3am)` man page for details on this extension.

Run with something like:

```
gawk -f testhome.awk <(getent passwd)    # bash/zsh and glibc
gawk -f testhome.awk /etc/passwd
```

You can confirm that your `gawk` binary supports extensions with:

```
BEGIN { 
  if (!("api_major" in PROCINFO)) 
    printf("No extension API.\n")
  else
    printf("Extension API v%s.%s.\n",PROCINFO["api_major"],PROCINFO["api_minor"])
}
```

---

Aside: `gawk` also comes with a small library function to read the `passwd` file, you can invoke it like:

```
gawk -i passwd.awk -- 'BEGIN { while(uu=getpwent()) {print uu;} endpwent(); }'
```

I prefer to use `getent` on Linux/glibc systems as it supports nsswitch.

Comment: Interesting.  I was not aware of `gawk` v4 offers this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is almost awk...

```
perl -F: -ane 'if(!-d $F[5]){ print "$F[0] $F[2] $F[6]" }' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which

- uses `gawk` and `/bin/sh`
- does the directory check with some external command
- but does it a safe and secure way

Code:

```
gawk -F: '{
    cmd="IFS=\"\" read -r dir; [ -d \"$dir\" ]; echo $?";
    print $6 |& cmd;
    cmd |& getline x;
    close(cmd);
    if (x) print x " " $1 " " $3 " " $7
}' /etc/passwd
```

explained:

- `IFS="" read -r dir; [ -d "$dir" ]; echo $?` is a shell code which reads a path from stdin and outputs `0` if it is a directory, else `1`
- `print $6 |& cmd` pipes the filename to the command. `|&` is a GNU-awk extension.
- `cmd |& getline x` reads the output of the command into GNU-awk
- `close(cmd)` finishes the command, so the next line can execute one again
- `if (x)` executes the `print` only if `x` is not `0` (so the directory does not exist)

I do not recommend to do it this way, though, because it is very slow and clumsy.  But **this recipe is safe**, such that irregular input cannot do harm.  (It is unlikely that `/etc/passwd` contains harmful data, but perhaps somebody wants to use it with data from a non-trusted source).

If you cannot use `gawk`, this is unfortunate.  In that case you do not have `|&`.  Normal `awk` only can do one of the following three:

- `print "data" | cmd; close(cmd)`: Pipe data into a command
- `getline data < cmd; close(cmd)`: Read data from a command
- `ret = system(cmd)`: Get the command's return code

"Normal" `awk` simply cannot pipe data into a script and get something out of it again at the same time (at least I did not find a way for it), so you need some intermediate file (tempfile) which is even more clumsy.

The interesting observation is, that such an easy task can be done with the shell alone, too:

```
dump_problems()
{
have=0;
while IFS=: read -r user pw id grp gcos dir shl;
do
  [ -d "$dir" ] && continue;
  echo "$user $id $shl";
  have=1;
done </etc/passwd;
return $have;
}

dump_problems && echo ALL OK >&2 || echo "Problems were found" >&2
```

You do not need `bash`, each normal Bourne-shell can execute above code.

Note that above shell code is a bit more elaborate than really needed, but this shall be a pointer on how to really work with it (for people not fully experienced in how shell works).