# Displaying "No Results" When AWK Command has no output

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have the following code, thank-you to the people who helped me [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195134/how-do-you-check-if-a-file-exists-within-awk-d-filename-failing)

```
awk -F: '{if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 1) {print "The directory " $6 " does not exist for user " $1 }}' /etc/passwd
```

However, I was silly, and didn't explain my full problem. Rather than change the question on people, I figured I'd open a new question.

My goal is to output a list of users who have a home directory set in /etc/passwd that points to a folder that doesn't exist. (The above code successfully does this).

The problem I'm now running into is that I'd like to display "No Results" rather than a blank page, if every user does in fact have a home directory that exists.

So for example, if I run that code on a default RHEL system I get the following output:

```
# awk -F: '{if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 1) {print "The directory " $6 " does not exist for user " $1 }}' /etc/passwd
The directory /var/adm does not exist for user adm
The directory /var/spool/uucp does not exist for user uucp
The directory /var/gopher does not exist for user gopher
The directory /var/ftp does not exist for user ftp
The directory /var/empty/saslauth does not exist for user saslauth
```

The users listed above, really don't matter because they can't login, so I'd like to update my code to account for this like the following:

```
awk -F: '{if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 1 && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" ) {print "The directory " $6 " does not exist for user " $1 }}' /etc/passwd
```

This works as intended and no results are displayed, but I really want it to display "No Results", rather than not displaying anything. (This may seem like a silly requirement, but I'm going to be using this command in an automated tool which works a bunch better if there is output to look at).

I've googled and found a few examples of using NR, but haven't gotten it working right. I've also seen || and echo "No Results" on some types of commands, but can't seem to get that working either.

Google has not been helping me with other options, so I greatly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

- use a `BEGIN` block to set a flag
- unset the flag when your current test finds a missing directory
- check to see if the flag is still set in a `END` block and if so print your message

e.g.

```
awk -F: '
BEGIN{nores=1;} 
{if(system( "[ -d " $6 " ]") == 1 && $7 != "/sbin/nologin" ) {print "The directory " $6 " does not exist for user " $1; nores=0 }} 
END{if (nores) print "No results";}
' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Thank-you. This is exactly what I wanted! I tried that general technique earlier, but I'm not familiar enough with AWK to have done it right!

Comment: @Doug - awk is your friend. It's almost as day to day useful as grep, find, and sed - and a lot easier to debug than any of those when things go wrong. A little time learning it will pay you back many times over.